# Why is REST call including <pre> element in JSON response?

Tags: node.js, json, rest

This is my first attempt at building an Angular app using a REST API written in NodeJS.  No additional frameworks are used beyond native NodeJS modules.  I have a test .html that calls the API, but it has problems processing the API call.  I'm using the HTTP NodeJS module.

The response in my browser wraps the JSON in an `<pre>` element like this...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">JSON DATA GOEST HERE</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an app.js module that executes a database query. The database call returns a JavaScript object that is passed to the `_sendJSONResponse()` function.

I don't know why the `<pre>` element is getting added.

The REST call to `https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php` returns nearly identical format but without the `<pre>` wrapping element.

```
_sendJSONResponse = function(res, data) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: My guess is it's not, something client-side is causing this. If that's provably not the case (by looking at your network tab,) then whatever is proxying your node.js server is doing it.

Comment: Which browser?  I think this is the browser *helping* you by formatting the json for display. Can you see the raw response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of snooping and questioning other more experienced folks, it turned out to be a CORS issue in Chrome.  I was loading my index.html directly (file://index.html).  I set my NodeJS service to load the file and things automagically worked.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is just your browser giving you a 'good viewing experience' - what happens if you call the REST endpoint in your Angular client? If you supply the headers correctly your response should be valid JSON.

Comment: Well, the Angular client is what led me down this rabbit hole.  It isn't working the way I expected so I tried to view the response in the browser.  I navigate to the API URL in Chrome to view the response.  I navigated to the w3schools API example in Chrome and it did not wrap the result in <pre>.  Interestingly, when I navigate to my API URL in MS Edge, it downloads what I think is the correct JSON.

Comment: Corrections...Well, the Angular client is what led me down this rabbit hole.  It isn't working the way I expected so I tried to view the response in the browser.  I navigate to the API URL in Chrome to view what I thought is the raw response (`http://localhost/api/somelist`).  I navigated to the w3schools API example in Chrome and it did not wrap the result in `<pre>`, which made me think it was something in my code.  Do you have any guidance on how I should set my headers correctly?  I'm a database person, so I am relatively ignorant to the whole REST API and `http` thing.

Comment: If you need help with your Angular REST call, I will need to see some code there, viewing your REST endpoint in the browser shouldn't worry you too much and only be a way for quick testing - I can recommend https://www.getpostman.com/ to test REST APIs, enter your URL there and see what's up

Comment: The response headers were a problem.  This was as much a lesson in debugging in a browser as it was Node/Angular.  Thanks for the pointers.